# How to loop through an associative array?

Tags: php

This is my array:

```
 $data = array(
        'user_id'               => $profile_data['user_id'],
        'sender_id'             => $session_user_id,
        'sender_first_name'     => $user_data['first_name'],
        'photo_url'             => 'null',
        'time'                  => time(),
        'status'                => $_POST['status']

        );
```

This is my function:

```
function post($data) {

    array_walk($data, 'array_sanitize');

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO status ($fields) VALUES ($data) ");

    if ($data['sender_id'] == 1) {
//code
    }
}
```

How to check if the value of 'sender_id' is 1, for example?

Comment: So what is wrong with `if ($data['sender_id'] == 1) {`? I don't see why a foreach loop is needed here ... or any other code than the already-in-there- `if` ... and you should check your data perhaps even outside that function, at least in front of preparing your sql.

Comment: The problem is that you overwrote the variable `$data`. It no longer contains the original array, now it contains the string you created with `implode`. Use different variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can just say:

```
if ( $data['sender_id'] == 1 )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

but in general, if you need to look around an array, this is how you do it

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    if ( $key == 'sender_id' && $value == 1 )
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn you were quicker than me, thumbs up.

Comment: Why is this loop better than just using `$data['sender_id']`?

Comment: @Barmar I updated my answer, I totally overlooked the fact it's just a simple array.

Answer (score 1):

Don't overwrite a variable if you want to be able to check it, use different variables:

```
$data_str = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $data) . '\'';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO status ($fields) VALUES ($data_str) ");

if ($data['sender_id'] == 1) {
    // code
}
```